# Java DTO com Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou tentando implementar DTO e estou tendo uma dor de cabeça sem tamanho. Gostaria de uma ajuda. Segue meu projeto, com spring boot 2.

tenho 3 tabelas @entity da seguinte forma.

Abstract Cliente com apenas 1 atributo, o "id" e o respectivo get and set.
2 classes que herdam de cliente,

PessoaFisica

---

PessoaJuridica

cada uma com seus respectivos atributos (cpf, nome, cnpj, razão social....) e métodos.

Criei 3 classes DTO, ClienteDTO, PFDTO e PJDTO.

Na Classe ClienteResource, que é meu @RestController, eu tenho entre outros metodos, o metodo inserir, que ao inves de usar o Entity Cliente, quero que use o ClienteDTO

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<Void> inserir(@RequestBody Cliente objetoCliente) {
objetoCliente = clienteService.inserir(objetoCliente);
URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(objetoCliente.getId()).toUri();
return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
}
```

E quero que mude para isso

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<Void> inserir(@RequestBody ClienteDTO objetoClienteDTO) {
Cliente objetoCliente = clienteService.converteParaDTO(objetoClienteDTO);
objetoCliente = clienteService.inserir(objetoCliente);
URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(objetoCliente.getId()).toUri();
return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
}
```

Acontece que no ClienteService, minha service do cliente, o metodo
converteParaDTO esta dando erro:

```
public Cliente converteParaDTO(ClienteDTO objetoClienteDTO) {
if (objetoClienteDTO instanceof PessoaFisicaDTO) {
return new PessoaFisica(objetoClienteDTO.getNome(), objetoClienteDTO., objetoClienteDTO.getRg(),
objetoClienteDTO.getEmail(), objetoClienteDTO.getDataDeNascimento(), objetoClienteDTO.getNaturalidade(),
objetoClienteDTO.getProfissao(), objetoClienteDTO.getGenero(), objetoClienteDTO.getEstadoCivil(), objetoClienteDTO.getPessoaFisicaTipo()) {
};
}
if (objetoClienteDTO instanceof PessoaJuridicaDTO) {
return new PessoaJuridica(objetoClienteDTO.getRazaoSocial(), objetoClienteDTO.getNomeFantasia(),
objetoClienteDTO.getDataDeConstituicao(), objetoClienteDTO.getInscricaoEstadual(), objetoClienteDTO.getInscricaoFederal(),
objetoClienteDTO.getPessoaJuridicaTipo());
}
return null;
}
```

O erro é o seguinte: Meu ClienteDTO tem apenas 2 atributos, id e nome.
Os demais atributos e metodos são especificos de cada classe. Então o objetoClienteDTO.getInscricaoEstadual() por exemplo, nao existe, entre outros.

Queria uma ajuda como resolvo esse problema. Como chamo uma classe ou outra (PFDTO ou PJDTO) através de um único método.

Comment: Se você tem perguntas adicionais, clique no botão azul "Faça uma pergunta" que está lá em cima ao invés de postar perguntas como se fossem respostas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que acontece é que a biblioteca de serialização olha para o tipo declarado na assinatura do método (que no seu caso é `ClienteDTO`) e tenta converter pra ele.

Uma alternativa é dar uma "dica" para o serializador qual subclasse ele deve instanciar.

É possível fazer isso com a anotação `JsonTypeInfo`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PessoaFisicaDTO.class, name = "fisica"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PessoaJuridicaDTO.class, name = "juridica")
})
class ClienteDTO {
  private Long id;
  private String type;
}
```

```
class PessoaFisicaDTO extends ClienteDTO {
  private String email;
  private String profissao;
}
```

```
class PessoaJuridicaDTO extends ClienteDTO {
  private String dataDeConstituicao;
  private String inscricaoEstadual;
}
```

Neste caso foi definido no `property` que haverá um campo `type` no JSON. Este, por sua vez, poderá ter os valores `fisica` ou `juridica`. O serializador lerá esta informação e tentará converter para o tipo adequado.

Usando esta solução, seu JSON deverá conter um atributo a mais informando o tipo:

```
{ 
    "type": "fisica",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "profissao":"desenvolvedor"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa fazer o `cast` de `ClienteDTO` para `PessoaFisicaDTO` ou `PessoaJuridicaDTO` antes de pegar os atributos, imaginando que realmente chegue uma instância de cada no seu método. Exemplo:

```
public Cliente converteParaDTO(ClienteDTO objetoClienteDTO) {
    if (objetoClienteDTO instanceof PessoaFisicaDTO) {
        PessoaFisicaDTO pfDto = (PessoaFisicaDTO) objetoClienteDTO;
        return new PessoaFisica(pfDto.getNome(),...
```

E para `PessoaJuridicaDTO`:

```
    if (objetoClienteDTO instanceof PessoaJuridicaDTO) {
        PessoaJuridicaDTO pjDto = (PessoaJuridicaDTO) objetoClienteDTO;
        return new PessoaJuridica(pjDto.getRazaoSocial(), ...
```

Contudo, o melhor mesmo seria evitar este `instanceof` usando um único serviço e implementar dois serviços separados: um para pessoa física e outro para pessoa jurídica.